# SMS Through Email

Tags: email, sms

I know this is a subject that has been well covered here and throughout the web, so I am not asking for a list of carrier emails, however my question is how to send a text without knowing the users carrier and preferably without going through a third party.

The only solution that I thought of would be send out to all carriers. I would only be sending to US carriers, however would a large number of failed emails slow the mail server at all or cause any other problems?

Any advice on this solution or thoughts of others would be great.

Comment: Sending to "all carriers" sounds like a Really Bad Idea.

Comment: Related question: Is there the equivalent of a **WHOIS** for Cell Phone numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep sending messages to a carrier to numbers that don't exist, you'll start to get blocked as a spammer. Probably best to either ask your users for which carrier they use or use a gateway like [Twilio](http://twilio.com) (where I work) or the various others out there.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using CloudVox's digits API.  The carrier's aren't always up to date, from what I can tell it basically relies on the original carrier you got your phone number from.  i.e. You had verizon but switched to AT&T to get an iPhone and kept the same phone number, CloudVox API would likely tell you the number is still a verizon number.  However, I used this for my existing user's and then exposed a select box for them to choose their provider.

http://digits.cloudvox.com/

Comment: Link is dead, Blake. Just FYI.

Comment: Thanks @jp2code. As mentioned by Runscope (John) above, you should be asking users for their carrier and sending only to that email.  If you send lots of emails to non-existent email addresses, its very likely the domains you are sending to will black list all future emails coming from your ip/domain.

Comment: I just happened across this. I was looking for a way to have my website receive and process text messages.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a reason to consider using a third-party API provider, I'd recommend Plivo (I work here), among many other providers, to bypass the carrier lookup issue and have more flexibility.

It will require some extra legwork than sending to carrier emails, but you will less likely to fret over the deliverability. For example, check out the email and sms gateway built using [Plivo and Mailgun API](https://plivo.com/docs/getting-started/sms-to-email-gateway-integration/).