# Is there a way out if i want to build a java application which does not require the use of a gsm modem?

Tags: java, telephony

I want to build a java application which would be able to send sms to any mobile number.But the problem is that i do not have a gsm modem.Is there any alternate way available.Can i use my own phone as a modem by connecting it with a usb cable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can connect your own phone via cable and send/receive SMS that way. It would however probably be easier to use some online service that can convert e-mail to SMS. That way your application becomes a lot simpler.

Some SO questions regarding e-mail to SMS:

- [Testing Email to SMS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075179/testing-email-to-sms)
- [SMS Through Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523670/sms-through-email)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in most cases for modern phones, but it depends on phone model. What's the model of your phone?

Comment: The phone model is Nokia c200

Comment: You can use Nokia PC Suite Connectivity API for this. I don't know if this API can be used in Java. I can suggest you to write small C++ console application for sending messages and execute it from your java app.

Answer (score 0):

You require to have a subscription account with any third party `SOAP` or simple `HTTP` based SMS Service providers. As an example [`SimpleWire / OpenMarket`](http://www.openmarket.com/) is a third party messaging provider that sends SMS on your behalf and also lets your server app delivery status of that message. You need to integrate its API with your your server app and your app does not require any GSM modem to connect with for SMS processing.